# How to prevent entering settings when using Monkey Test

Tags: android, testing, monkey

I have a monkey test with my application in android device(LG G4).

The command is

`adb shell monkey -p {package name} -v 2000`

But it may accidentally enter settings and change my device's default value.

How to prevent it ?

Comment: what does mean of Default setting of device??

Comment: default value in settings, like wifi on ...etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monkey support blacklist, you could your setting package name in blacklist then run Monkey, Monkey will not perform test in package which you set in blacklist.

you can do like this:

1. `adb shell pm list packages` get your setting package name
2. open a blacklist.txt file, and put package name in it, then push it to your device like /sdcard/blacklist.txt
3. run Monkey with --pkg-blacklist-file like this: `adb shell monkey --pkg-blacklist-file /sdcard/blacklist.txt`

Answer (score 3):

You can use screen pinning. Start the app/package you want to test. Pin it. Then start monkey with e.g. adb shell monkey -p {package name} -v 2000. This worked for me on an Android device running Nougat (7.0).